# What is the best way to store incoming streaming data?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, hbase, spark-streaming, parquet

What is a better choice for a long-term store (many writes, few reads) of data processed through Spark Streaming: Parquet, HBase or Cassandra? Or something else? What are the trade-offs?

Comment: I would suggest cassandra because of all the database capabilities that it has and among alll the databases it has the fastest write.

Comment: pls check my answer. Hope that will help!

Answer (score 1):

***In my experience we have used Hbase as datastore for spark streaming data(we also has same scenario many writes and few reads), since we are using hadoop, hbase has native integration with hadoop and it went well..***

- Above we have used tostore hight rate of messages coming over from solace.
- HBase is well suited for doing Range based scans. Casandra is known for availablity and many other things...
- However, I can also observe one general trend in many projects, they are simply storing rawdata in hdfs (parquet + avro) in partitioned structure through spark streaming  with spark dataframe(`SaveMode.Append)` and they are processing rawdata with Spark

Ex of partitioned structure in hdfs  : 
`completion ofbusinessdate/environment/businesssubtype/message type` etc....
in this case there is no need for going to Hbase or any other data store.

But one common issue in above approach is when you are getting small and tiny files, through streaming then you would need to `repartion(1`) or `colelese` or `FileUtils.copymerge` to meet block size requirements to single partitioned file. Apart from that above approach also would be fine.

Here is some thing called **CAP theorm** based on which decision can be taken. 
[image]

1. Consistency (all nodes see the same data at the same time).
2. Availability (every request receives a response about whether it
   succeeded or failed).
3. Partition tolerance (the system continues to
   operate despite arbitrary partitioning due to network failures)

Casandra supports AP.

Hbase supports CP.

Look at detailed analysis given [here](http://bigdatanoob.blogspot.in/2012/11/hbase-vs-cassandra.html)

Comment: Was my answer helpful ? please feel free to ask questions. Thanks!